# .Net Maui Content Page vs Xamarin Content Page

Tags: xamarin, maui, content-pages

I am converting a Shell Xamarin app to a Shell .Net Maui. In my Xamarin project, one of my detail pages (called from the MainPage) is a Xmal ContentPage with all (100%) of the Content built in the code behind.  I have a BuildForm() method called in the OnAppearing() override method that builds the form and at the end of it put all of my controls into a Stacklayout and set the contents to that stacklayout.

```
            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children = { connectionView, scrollView, slbuttons, slbuttons1, btnShareAuthority },
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20),
        };
        Content = stackLayout;
```

This detail page has a shared sub page to list relevant messages. This message page can be called by any one of the detail pages to show messages relevant to that detail. When navigating back, using the apps back button from this messages page the OnAppearing is called and then the BuildForm() method. The page is rebuilt and the page show properly.
Now for the problem. In my Maui app I attempt to do the exact same thing. Navigating from the MainPage to the detail page all works fine. However when navigating back from the messages page (device back button) the app seems to just die on the `Content = stackLayout;` line. (As a side note stacklayout in the Maui app is really a grid as Maui needs the scrollview to be in a grid.) I do not get any error messages or unhandled exception, it just stops and the app is left on the messages page. I then can tap the back button again and it will navigate to the details page but this time it will be a blank page.
I have come up with a work around and that is to determine if the page Content is null. So in my OnAppearing() method I do

```
    if(Content == null)
    {
        BuildForm();
    }
```

This will be called both on the initial load from the Mainpage and navigating back from the Messages page. In the BuildForm() method, which will be called only on the initial load of the form, I test it also:

```
        if(Content == null)
        Content = stacklayout;
```

So as it appears the Content in a page's life cycle (at least in my case) can only be set once. I even tried to set the Content to null then set it to the newly build grid, but that won't work either. Luckily for me the Detail page data is static throughout this navigation.
So the big question: Is this intended? I searched Maui Documentation and found nothing helpful. Why does it work in Xamarin but not in Maui.
Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  I'm able to dynamically set the `Content` of a page multiple times in a MAUI app without problem

Comment: Are any of the `Children` stored in members of the class? If so, do you create new ones each time in OnAppearing? That is necessary; can't re-use a View in a new place unless it is first removed from its old parent.

Comment: Could this be a Thread issue by any chance? You are not making a UI change on the UI thread? I don't see enough code so this is just a speculation.

Comment: @Jason - there is a lot going on in this app by the time I get to this page/issue. So to strip it down will take some effort, but I'll try, it'll be next week

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve if by Children you mean the Children of the StackLayouts the button & the ScrollView; They are all recreated in the BuildForm() method. The only one that is not recreated is the connectionView as it was instantiated on the original call to the form

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - as a result of your question, I went back and got a new instance of the connectionView, which is a StackLayout control, in the OnAppearing() method. I took out my tests to determine if Content is null or not and it worked as I would expect. So as it turns out, in Maui I needed to re-instantiate everything whereas in Xamarin I did not need to. So my question still stands, is this intended or was this a fluke of nature? In either case thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It was never *guaranteed* in Xamarin that you could re-use a view without explicitly removing it from its old parent. (UI systems are not usually written to automatically cope with such a change, without informing old parent. Might work; might cause problems.) For performance, the way Maui renders cross-platform controls as native platform controls is different than what Xamarin did. Apparently, this is a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there is a difference between Xamarin and Maui in this respect. @ToolmakeSteve asked about the `Children` which caused me to make sure all children are instantiated in the OnAppearing method. The custom control connectionView was not. After re-instantiating it in the OnAppearing all worked as expected. The OnAppearing now looks like this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    connectionView = new ConnectionView();
    WarrantInfo = new Warrant();
    WarrantInfo = viewModel.WarrantInfo;
    BuildForm();
}
```

Comment: If this is truly acceptable as an answer you should accept it;